# join hive tables on minimal difference between values

Tags: mysql, hadoop, join, hiveql

I have 2 hive tables T1 and T2, both of them have different IDs.

```
T1: ID1 | value1 
T2: ID2 | value2
```

I want to join T1 and T2. For each value1 in T1 i need to add ID2 (exactly one and not used before) where ABS(value1-value2) is minimal.
For example T1 looks like:

```
ID1  | value1
 1   |  20
 2   |  17
 3   |  10
```

and T2:

```
ID2  | value2
 a   |  19
 b   |  12
 c   |  14
 d   |  8
```

Result should be:

```
ID1  | value1 | ID2
 1   |  20    |  a
 2   |  17    |  c
 3   |  10    |  b
```

I understand HiveQL has some limitations compared to SQL.
But SQL solution would work too, just to get an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to solve in Hive in an efficient because you have to do all the combinations (cross product) to get the smallest differences. You can try something like this if you let the requirement "exactly one and not used before" out.

```
select ID1, value1, ID2 from 
(
select ID1, value1, ID2, value2, row_number() over (partition by value1 order by diff asc) as lessdiff from 
(
select ID1, abs(value1 - value2) as  diff, ID2 , value1, value2 from  t1 join t2 on 1=1
) X1
) 
X2 where lessdiff = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well on small tables, but when t1 has 65k rows and t2 485k it uses only 2 CPU VCores out of 106. There is only 1 mapper and mapping progress doesnt seem to change after hours of working. How can i use rest of the cluster to speed up this task?

Comment: could you try split the file used in the t1 table in 10 smaller files and check if it works?

Comment: splited t2 in 50 parts but instead of 50 mappers i got 7... wonder if i gzip each part it will force to assign single mapper to each part, but not sure if hive understands gzip.

Comment: there are flags to merge input files. check those flags. CombineInput shousnt be set

Comment: i did `set -v` and it said `hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=false`